# How to use Workbook Object

Tags: excel, vba

I want just get the workbook name. Why VBA returns a error when i try use Workbook´s Name property directly, like this:

```
MsgBox "workbook name = " & Workbook.Name
```

The compiler says: Variable not declared. Workbook is an object. Why do i have to declare a variable associated to it?

These work:

```
MsgBox "workbook name = " & ThisWorkbook.Name

MsgBox "workbook name = " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
```

Why do I have to use Application properties (ThisWorkbook and ActiveWorkbook) instead of Workbook.Name directly?

Comment: It's not necessary to SHOUT when you're asking questions here. We can all read quite well. Typing in all CAPS makes your question harder to read, won't get you answers any faster, and is quite annoying to people. Please don't do so. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I didn´t understand. Is my question typed in CAPS?

Comment: You don't remember what you posted? :-) Your question **title** was all CAPS. as you can see in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20709266/revisions). Please don't do that, as I said. :-) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I will pay attention.

Comment: A:"What's the title of the book?" B:"Uh... what book? What are you talking about?! Does not compute! Error! error! ERROR!!" A:"Sorry, I mean, what is the title of that book you put on the table over there?" B:"Railsea."

Answer (score 3):

`Workbook` is not an object

`Workbook` is the `class` which represents all the workbooks,

(for more details: http://www.functionx.com/vbaexcel/topics/workbooks.htm)

and `ThisWorkbook(or ActiveWorkbook)` is the `instance`

classes don't have values for properties (except static) .i.e. in other words, you cannot access `instance variables` through a `class`.

i hope you understand.

Comment: The most difficulty for me is to understand when a key word is a object, a property or a method. For example: ActiveWorkbook is a property of Application object, second MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb220820(v=office.12).aspx - but it can also be an object (an instance)?

Comment: Objects can also be the values for properties of some other class. here ActiveWorkbook is a reference to the current workbook object and it is also a property of the Application class